# reading HTTP headrs in django

Tags: django, django-views

i want to figure out a way to read http header which is having following row format `

```
vid=103;state=3;mac=0016ea3619fc;sid=70B50E18-7286-11E1-B91D-
AAAF4724019B;bssid=2c3f38aaabe0
```

i'm trying to use request.META but i dont have any clue on getting the state parameter out of the http header can anyone help me doing this ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the header is called "data" you could access it like this in your view:

```
data = request.META['data']
items = dict(tuple(d.split('=') for d in data.split(';')))
state = items['state']
```

Comment: in request.META['data'], is data attribute is predefined one or is it a variable?

Comment: Assuming that `vid=103;state=3;mac=0016ea3619fc;sid=70B50E18-7286-11E1-B91D-
AAAF4724019B;bssid=2c3f38aaabe0` is the value of an HTTP Header then `data` should be replaced with the key name of that header.